# Would this be a suitable question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

We've had this question [about elevator buttons](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7652/what-is-the-reason-for-concave-round-buttons-in-elevators-closed) asked - and closed - on the DIY site.

I've just thought it might be suitable for here.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a great question. We need more questions that aren't software-related. Send it over.

Comment: Just migrated it now.

Comment: +1 - totally agree - we do seem be stuck in the rut of ux being seen as related only to software, websites and mobile apps, but as JJG said: "The user experience mindset is an acquired condition for which there is no cure" and so it effects everything we engage with. Unfortunately - that's our inside->out view - not everyone else's outside->in view...